# jQuery datepicker not works when overlaps other form elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker together with jQuery mobile.
When jQuery datepicker is shown and overlaps other form elements it will not pick the selected date. Instead it select the background form element. Is there any way to solve this so it works?

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td><label for="txtAnkomstLS">Date 1:</label>  </td><td><label for="txtAvresaLS">Date 2:</label>   </td></tr><tr><td>

<input type="text" id="txtAnkomstLS" data-mini="true" /></td><td>             
<input type="text" id="txtAvresaLS" data-mini="true" /></td></tr></table>



<label for="select-choice-3" class="select">Field 1:</label>
            <table width="100%">                
            <tr><td width="50%">        <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-mini="true"  data-theme="c">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>

            </select></td><td width="50%">      <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2" data-mini="true"  data-theme="c">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>

            </select></td></tr></table>


<label for="select-choice-3" class="select">Field 2:</label>
            <table width="100%">                
            <tr><td width="50%">        <select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3" data-mini="true"  data-theme="c">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>

            </select></td><td width="50%">      <select name="select-choice-4" id="select-choice-4" data-mini="true"  data-theme="c">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>

            </select></td></tr></table>


         <label for="search">Textinput:</label>
         <input type="text" id="search" value=""  data-mini="true" />
```

```
$(function() {

    $( "#txtAnkomstLS" ).datepicker({ 
   });

    $( "#txtAvresaLS" ).datepicker({ 

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wQRDx/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An dirty solution is to use an override

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    beforeShow: function ( input, inst ) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                zIndex: 10000
            });
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4AgVn/)

Comment: @Avishek there is no property called `$.ui.dialog.maxZ` and your solution is not working. Update the demo fiddle and check if you want

Comment: @Avishek checkout this demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4AgVn/1/ and see yourself whether your solution is working

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works like a charm! Saved a lot of work! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround of your problem, it sets the z-index of the widget to max, so it can be selected.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    beforeShow: function ( input, inst ) {
        inst.dpDiv.css({
            zIndex: function(index, value) {
                return $.ui.dialog.maxZ + 1;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help :) but the solution below works. tesded in all major browsers.

Comment: Yes, but unfountunatly it doesn't work correct. Thank you anyway :)